# Static background in kivy

Tags: python, background, kivy

I was wondering if there is a way to get a static background in a Kivy application with a screen manager. With static, I mean that the background remains as it is, even when switching screens. I am using a .kv file for the layout. I'd guess it has something to do with the placement order within a .kv file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a float layout as the root widget in every screen and add to that float layout the image and the other layout in your screen, here is a code example in kv:

```
Screen: # Screen 1
    id: Home
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            source: "path to the image"

        BoxLayout: # Here you put your other layout
            # And here the code you had

Screen: # Screen 2
    id: Another Screen
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            source: "path to the image"

        BoxLayout: # Here you put your other layout
            # And here the code you had
```

This is the solution that I know, it might not be perfect for you, but I will leave the other options to others...

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
FloatLayout:
    Image:
    ScreenManager:
```

would be enough I think but be careful, if the transition of ScreenManager is ShaderTransition(or a sub-class thereof), it doesn't respect the pixels in the background, so the animation during the transition may not work properly.